# Changing public variables from a method

Tags: java

I have some variables:

```
float firstFloatSize  = 0.0;
float secondFloatSize = 1.0;
float thirdFloatSize  = 2.0;
float fourthFloatSize = 3.0;
```

I would like to change these variables from a method, which would receive the name and the new  value of the variable as a parameter. Like this:

```
public void changeValue("firstFloatSize", 3.0);
```

If I ran that, I would change the value of the variable "firstFloatSize" to 3.0.

Would this be somehow possible? I know I could create a wrapper class for the floats and implemented such a method in that class, but I'm just curious if I could achieve this in another way.

Comment: That sounds vaguely reflection-related, which means that no, you can't. (more specifically, you can, but shouldn't without VERY good reason)

Comment: why don't you want to use getters and setters?

Comment: did you try using a Map<String, Float> ?

Comment: create enums and use them.

Comment: Changing the field this way is dubious, but also remember that `3.0` is a `double` not a `float` and refection actually cares about such distinctions.  Note:  I would avoid using `float` unless you have a *very* good reason.  Just use double is less error prone in 99% of cases.

Answer (score 1):

use `setProperty` from apache common `PropertyUtils`

```
PropertyUtils.setProperty(this,"firstFloatSize", 3.0);
```

Comment: user3580294: One of the other easy way for people who are not comfortable with reflections.

Comment: This still breaks silently whenever the field name changes.

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu: You are right. Need to be careful if the property name is gonna change.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* do this using reflection, but it would create code that would be difficult to maintain. For example, changing a variable name will break the reflection code: you would not notice that until runtime. You'd also be circumventing encapsulation (perhaps moot given you note that the member data are public).

I'd suggest you do this in the normal way, with set and get methods.

Answer (score 0):

If the main discriminatory point of these fields is the "first", "second", etc., then you could use an array to store the values, und set up a method which changes the values according to the index in the array:

```
float[] floatSizes = new float[]{ 0, 1, 2, 3 };

public void changeValueAtPosition(int index, float newValue){
    floatSizes[index] = newValue;
}
```

This example of course lacks some common guards on the parameters (like ensuring the index is valid), and could be improved by using a Standard Type (like an enum) instead of a primitive int to switch the value you want to change.

Changing the "firstFloatSize" would then be possible by calling `changeValueAtPosition(0, 3);`

To reiterate the point of other answers: Do Not Use Reflection if there are other, simpler ways. Reflection-based code is a maintenance nightmare in any project size > 100 LOC.

Answer (score 0):

You have basically two options:

Either write a custom dispatch method:

```
public void changeValue(String fieldName, float newValue)
{
     // Java 6 style:
     if("firstFloatSize".equals(fieldName)) {
         targetClass.firstFloatSize = newValue;
     } else if("secondFloatSize".equals(fieldName)) {
         targetClass.secondFloatSize = newValue;
     } else if // ... and so on

     // or, alternatively, Java 7 style:
     switch(fieldName)
     {
         case "firstFloatSize": targetClass.firstFloatSize = newValue; break;
         case "secondFloatSize": targetClass.secondFloatSize = newValue; break;
         // ... and so on
     } 
}
```

Or use reflection:

```
public void changeValue(String fieldName, float newValue)
{
  try 
  {
    Field field = targetObject.getClass().getField(fieldName);
    field.setFloat(targetObject, newValue);
  }
  catch( ... ) { ... }
}
```

I don't know if your floats are fields in the same class or another class. If it's the same class, you don't need the `targetObject`, obviously. Otherwise, of course, you need to replace `targetObject` with a reference to the object you want.

Note that both ways are not very nice as other comments already state. Both are not very maintainable and if, for example, you want to rename one of the floats in the future, then you have to manually check for all occurrences of the string, because your compiler cannot determine correctness in these cases.

Also (though this is kind of obvious), if you have multiple similar floats which you want to access like this, you could also create a single array and use an index (possibly backed by an enum) instead of a string to address them. But that goes too far away from the original question so I won't elaborate here further...

Comment: Starting from Java 7, the if-cascade can also be done by a switch over the String literals, which - IMHO - looks more elegant and less cluttered.

Comment: `getField(fieldName)` will not return private field and you will end up with `java.lang.NoSuchFieldException`use `.getDeclaredField(name)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use third party libraries.

But if you want to use Java raw APIs, below is a sample code..

```
public class ReflectionSample {

    private float value1 = 1.0f;

    public float getValue1() {
            return this.value1;
    }

    public void changeValue(String fieldName, float value) throws Exception {
            Field field = this.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
            boolean accessible = field.isAccessible();
            field.setAccessible(true);
            field.set(this, value);
            field.setAccessible(accessible);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            ReflectionSample sample = new ReflectionSample();
            sample.changeValue("value1", 3.0f);
            System.out.println(sample.getValue1());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**As a good coding practice.**

1. You should not have public variables in your class.
2. Variables should be private with proper get and set methods. That is one of the basic OOPs principle. Encapsulation.

**But back to your code.**
First there is a small problem in how you have defined float variables. these should be

```
float firstFloatSize  = 0.0f;
```

Now there are few ways you can achieve this.

1. Writing your own reflection based code.
2. Using conditional code something like below.
3. Using Apache PropertyUtils. Which uses reflection to set your property.

Still in the end your calling code should be calling a proper set method. Hope it helps.

`public void changeValue(String property, float value) {
        if(property.equals("firstFloatSize")) {
            firstFloatSize = value;
        } else if(property.equals("secondFloatSize")) {
        secondFloatSize = value;
        } else if(property.equals("thirdFloatSize")) {
        thirdFloatSize = value;
        } else {
           fourthFloatSize = value;
        }
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you need to set values this way, but this is what i came up without reflection:

```
public class PropertySetter {

    private float valOne;
    private float valTwo;
    private float valThree;
    private float valFour;

    public void setValue(FIELDS name, float value) {
        switch (name) {
            case valOne:
                valOne = value;
                break;
            case valTwo:
                valTwo = value;
                break;
            case valThree:
                valThree = value;
                break;
            case valFour:
                valFour = value;
                break;
            default:
                throw new AssertionError(name.name());
        }
    }

    public enum FIELDS {

        valOne,
        valTwo,
        valThree,
        valFour;
    }
}
```

however if reflection is allowed, then i would do this:

```
public class ReflectionSetter {

    private float valOne;
    private float valTwo;
    private float valThree;
    private float valFour;

    public boolean setValue(String name, float value) {
        Field[] fields = this.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field f : fields) {
            if (f.getName().equals(name)) {
                try {
                    f.setFloat(this, value);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(ReflectionSetter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

First method is a bit difficult to maintain because refactoring of this class would be a nightmare.
Second way is quite nice, because you only just need to know fieldname.